# .NET 3.5 - Stackframe's getmethod returns a property name prepended with unknown characters

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, stack-trace, jit

ISSUE: `StackFrame.GetMethod()` returns a property name prepended with unknown characters (**myProperty returned as __XY_myProperty**).

Recently we have added a property to an existing class. This class is used in ASP.NET. Every property in this class calls a custom securitycheck function that uses stacktrace to get the method name of the callee to perform actions based on that name.

The issue is, `StackFrame` returns this newly added property name (**myProperty**) prepended with unknown characters (**__XY_myProperty**) during the runtime. This happens only on a production machine. We couldn't reproduce in any other machines that have similar settings.

Here is a sample of code:

```
    // comments
    public returntype myProperty
    {
        get
        {
            security.checkSecurity();
            return returntype();
        }
        set
        {
            security.checkSecurity();
            if (value == null)
            {
                Row["abc"] = anothervale;
                                }
            else
            {
                Row["xyz"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    // comment
```

`StackFrame.GetMethod()` call in `security.checkSecurity()` returns myProperty method name as: __XY_myProperty

(`StackFrame.GetMethod()` call not shown in the above example.)

What we tried is:

1. Cleared ASP.NET Caches
2. Compared .NET patches
3. Restarted the server

None of these resolved the issue.

Server Info:

- Windows 2003
- Runs on VMWare (Does JIT optimizes differently on VMWare?)
- IIS 6
- NET 3.5
- ASP.NET project built in release mode
- DLLs compiled in debug mode to make stacktrace behave properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

A profiler that installed on the machine was altering the MSIL code for code instrumentation.

Code instrumentation is the process of being able to modify the code as it is being given to the .NET runtime for execution. When the CLR loads a class and executes its method, the method's IL code is compiled to native instructions during the just-in-time (JIT) compilation process. The Profiling API provided as part of the CLR allows you to intercept this process. Before a method gets JIT-compiled, you can modify its IL code.

Solution: Uninstalled the profiler and everything works fine. It proved StackTrace is not dependable.